# How do I make my discord.py bot 24/7 which I have coded from VS code

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I have coded a discord bot from VS code. How do I keep it ***24/7 active***

Comment: It is working and all, but it's not ***24/7***

Comment: You should look into a getting some sort of server. It's a type of dedicated computer that can be used for hosting files / programs 24/7. For example, a popular server hosting platform that is free and used a lot within the Discord Bot community is Heroku.

Comment: But I wanna keep the code on my computer. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Yes basically. The idea is to host the bot on a place that isn't your computer. This could be in the cloud on a cloud server or even a physical machine you have access to, such as a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I think Raspberry Pi is not free.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's multiple ways to achieve this, but without seeing the actual source code I am going to make some inferences.

## Option 1 - Quick Dirty Solution

Place your code in an infinite loop and include a sleep call so you can run your bot in intervals. This depends on your need, it can run every 5 minutes, every dew seconds, etc. You can then execute the python script locally and it will run until you close the application or an error crashes the application.

```
while True:
    sleep(5)
```

## Option 2 - A Little Better Solution

The same solution stated above, but run the python script within a container. This  will make your solution more portable.

## Option 3 - Take It To The Cloud

A robust solution would be to deploy your bot into the cloud. One of the easiest clouds to deploy to is heroku, which will make your application more fault tolerant.

Answer (score 0):

Make a `restarter.py` file on repl.it
add this code in that file:

```py
from time import sleep
from os import system
sleep(7)
system("python main.py")
```

and in your main.py file

replace `client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))` to

```py
try:
    client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
except pycord.errors.HTTPException:
    print("\n\n\nBLOCKED BY RATE LIMITS\nRESTARTING NOW\n\n\n")
    os.system("python restarter.py")
    os.system('kill 1')
```

Comment: I had that, but I had problems so I switched to VS code

Comment: what problems did you face?

Comment: because i have been using replit for like 2-3 months without any downtime unless I decide to switch it off for few updates

Comment: if you really want to use vscode you can try searching through this post https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-run-code-24-7-on-my-computer-preferably-on-VS-code

Comment: After a while of running replit gives some error in html and then it shuts down

Comment: yes that is because either discord blocks it or there is an over load on replit but I do have a way to bypass that too

Comment: i have edited my message above @GameMaker try using that it reduced the sudden shut down

Answer (score 0):

You should check out this great  tutorial from Tech With Tim where he explains how to host a bot 24/7 on heroku for free. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BPvg9bndP1U

Comment: I think ill switch to heroku, it seems better. Thanks